# Where is the duration value set in a willRotateToInterfaceOrientation notification?

Tags: ios

I see the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation notice arrive with a duration value and I'm wondering if it is under my control to alter this value and, if so, where?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve it in iOS 5+ version, u can call this method manually

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

but it is not recommended to call it manually although it works fine.

Comment: No reflection on the accuracy of your response, Krishna, but I think there's still something missing here.   

Such as why is this piece of information, duration, sent to us?  What are we suppose to do with it?  

And, if we are suppose to be able to set the duration so we can control the pace of the rotation, where do we set it legally without needing to do a hack?